# Same audio into gstreamer two results out

Tags: c++, c, gstreamer

I have found that if I send the same OGG/Vorbis audio into a gstreamer 1.0 pipeline within a program twice I get different audio out (similar, but not identical).  I have tried unreferencing the pipeline and rebuilding it between uses, but too no avail.  Something seems to maintain some sort of state.  The second version is the same as other second versions, with the same differences to the first.

I'm looking for reproducable results from a server processing audio, and this is getting in the way.

I'm sorry this is so long.  Getting it to reproduce and rebuild to pipeline seemed like a relevant thing to leave in.  I have reproduced this with several OGG/vorbis files (not empty though).  Call the file "a.ogg" and then running the program will produce "job1.raw" and "job2.raw" which have been different each time.

Thanks for any help,

Richard.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <glib.h>
#include <gst/gst.h>

typedef struct _Decoder2Data {
  GstElement * appsrc;
  GstElement * decodebin;
  GstElement * audioconvert;
  GstElement * audioresample;
  GstElement * queue1;
  GstElement * filesink;
  GstElement * pipeline;
  GstBus *bus;
  const char* request_id;
  const char* outdir;
  GMainLoop * main_loop;
} Decoder2Data;

void start_request(const char* caps_str, Decoder2Data * data);
void process_data(Decoder2Data * obj, char * audio, int audioSize);
void end_request(Decoder2Data* data);
void finish_request(Decoder2Data * data);
int create_pipeline(int argc, char *argv[], Decoder2Data * data);
void closeGstreamer(Decoder2Data * data);
void *g_loop_thread(void *ptr);

void start_request(const char* caps_str, Decoder2Data * data) {
  g_printerr("Test %s: Starting request\n", data->request_id);
  g_object_set(data->appsrc, "caps", NULL, NULL);
  if (data->outdir) {
    char path[128];
    sprintf(path, "%s/%s.raw", data->outdir, data->request_id);
    FILE *fp = fopen(path, "w+");
    if(fp != NULL) {
      fclose(fp);
      gst_element_set_state(data->pipeline, GST_STATE_PAUSED);
      gst_element_set_state(data->filesink, GST_STATE_NULL);
      g_object_set(data->filesink, "location", path, NULL);
      gst_element_set_state(data->filesink, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
    } else {
      g_warning("Test %s: Unable to open raw audio file %s.\n", data->request_id, path);
    }
  }
  gst_element_set_state(data->pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
  gst_element_set_state(data->filesink, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
  g_printerr("Test Started request\n");
}

void process_data(Decoder2Data * obj, char * audio, int audioSize) {
  GstFlowReturn ret;
  GstBuffer * buf = gst_buffer_new_and_alloc(audioSize);    
  gst_buffer_fill(buf, 0, audio, audioSize);
  g_signal_emit_by_name (obj->appsrc, "push-buffer", buf, &ret);
  if(ret != GST_FLOW_OK)
    g_warning("Test Pushing audio resulted in flow state %d\n", ret);
}

void end_request(Decoder2Data* data) {
  GstFlowReturn ret;
  g_signal_emit_by_name (data->appsrc, "end-of-stream", &ret);
}

GstElement * createElement(const char* name, const char* factoryName) {
  GstElement * ret = gst_element_factory_make(name, factoryName);
  if (!ret)
    g_printerr ("Test failed to create element of type '%s'\n", name);
  return ret;
}

// Handler for the pad-added signal
static void _connect_decoder(GstElement *src, GstPad *pad, Decoder2Data *data) {
  g_debug("Test _connect_decoder\n");
  GstPad * sink_pad = gst_element_get_static_pad (data->audioconvert, "sink");
  GstPadLinkReturn ret = gst_pad_link(pad, sink_pad);
  if (GST_PAD_LINK_FAILED (ret))
    g_printerr("Test Link failed with GstPadLinkError %d.\n", ret);
  else
    g_debug("Test Link succeeded.\n");
  g_debug("Test Connected audio decoder\n");
}

void gstLink(GstElement * src, GstElement * target) {
  if (!gst_element_link (src, target))
    g_printerr ("Test ----------------- elements could not be linked.\n");
}

static void _on_eos(GstElement *src, GstPad *pad, Decoder2Data *data) {
  g_debug("Test _on_eos\n");
  finish_request(data);
}

static void _on_error(GstElement *src, GstMessage *pad, Decoder2Data *data) {
  g_debug("Test _on_error\n");
  GError *err = NULL;
  gchar *dbg_info = NULL;
  gst_message_parse_error (pad, &err, &dbg_info);
  if (err) {
    size_t len = strlen(err->message);
    g_printerr("ERROR: %s", err->message);
  }
  g_error_free(err);
  g_free(dbg_info);
  finish_request(data);
}

void create_and_link(Decoder2Data * data) {
  data->appsrc = createElement("appsrc", "appsrc");
  data->decodebin = createElement("decodebin", "decodebin");
  data->audioconvert = createElement("audioconvert", "audioconvert");
  data->audioresample = createElement("audioresample", "audioresample");
  data->queue1 = createElement("capsfilter", "capsfilter");
  data->filesink = createElement("filesink", "filesink");
  g_object_set (data->appsrc, "is-live", TRUE, NULL);   
  const gchar *caps_str = "audio/x-raw,  channels=1, rate=16000, format=S16LE";
  GstCaps * caps = gst_caps_from_string(caps_str);
  g_object_set (data->queue1, "caps", caps, NULL);
  g_object_set (data->filesink, "location", "/dev/null", NULL);
  g_debug("Test Created GStreamer elements");
  data->pipeline = gst_pipeline_new("pipeline");
  if (!data->pipeline) {
    g_printerr ("Test pipe line could not be created.\n");
  }
  // Add all elements to the pipeline
  gst_bin_add_many (GST_BIN (data->pipeline), data->appsrc, data->decodebin, data->audioconvert, data->audioresample, data->queue1, data->filesink, NULL);
  gstLink(data->appsrc, data->decodebin);       
  g_signal_connect(data->decodebin, "pad-added", G_CALLBACK (_connect_decoder), data);       
  gstLink(data->audioconvert, data->audioresample);
  gstLink(data->audioresample, data->queue1);
  gstLink(data->queue1, data->filesink);
  g_debug("Linked GStreamer elements\n");
  // Create bus      
  data->bus = gst_element_get_bus(data->pipeline);
  gst_bus_add_signal_watch(data->bus);
  gst_bus_enable_sync_message_emission(data->bus);
  gst_pipeline_use_clock((GstPipeline*)data->pipeline, (GstClock*)NULL);
  g_signal_connect(data->bus, "message::eos", G_CALLBACK(_on_eos), data);
  g_signal_connect(data->bus, "message::error", G_CALLBACK(_on_error), data);
}

void finish_request(Decoder2Data * data) {
  g_printerr("Test finish_request %s\n", data->request_id);
  if (data->outdir) {
    gst_element_set_state(data->filesink, GST_STATE_NULL);
    g_object_set(data->filesink, "location", "/dev/null", NULL);
    gst_element_set_state(data->filesink, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
  }
  gst_element_set_state(data->pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
  // Destroy the old pipeline.
  gst_element_set_state(data->appsrc, GST_STATE_NULL);
  gst_element_set_state(data->decodebin, GST_STATE_NULL);
  gst_element_set_state(data->audioconvert, GST_STATE_NULL);
  gst_element_set_state(data->audioresample, GST_STATE_NULL);
  gst_element_set_state(data->queue1, GST_STATE_NULL);
  gst_element_set_state(data->filesink, GST_STATE_NULL);
  gst_object_unref(data->pipeline);
  // Build a new pipeline
  create_and_link(data);
  gst_element_set_state(data->pipeline, GST_STATE_READY);
  g_printerr("Rebuilt pipeline.");
  g_printerr("Finished request complete.\n");
}

int create_pipeline(int argc, char *argv[], Decoder2Data * data) {
  g_printerr("Test create_pipeline\n");
  gst_init (&argc, &argv);
  data->request_id = "<undefined>";
  data->outdir = "./";
  create_and_link(data);
  g_debug("Setting pipeline to READY\n");
  gst_element_set_state(data->pipeline, GST_STATE_READY);
  g_debug("Set pipeline to READY\n");
  return 0;
}

void closeGstreamer(Decoder2Data * data) {
  gst_object_unref (data->bus);
  gst_element_set_state (data->pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
  gst_object_unref (data->pipeline);
}

#include <pthread.h>

void *g_loop_thread(void *ptr) {
  g_debug("Test main loop thread started\n");
  Decoder2Data * data = (Decoder2Data*) ptr;
  data->main_loop = g_main_loop_new(NULL, FALSE);
  g_debug("Test main loop created, executing g_main_loop_run\n");
  g_main_loop_run(data->main_loop);  // This is blocking    
  g_debug("Test main loop thread ENDED\n");
  return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  Decoder2Data data;
  memset (&data, 0, sizeof (data));
  create_pipeline(argc, argv, &data);
  pthread_t thread;
  int ret = pthread_create(&thread, NULL, g_loop_thread, &data);
  if (ret != 0) {
    g_printerr("Test Thread not started");
    return -1;
  }
  usleep(250000);  // Wait a bit to make sure the thread started
  g_printerr("Test starting test\n");
  data.request_id = "job1";
  start_request("", &data);
  FILE * file = fopen("./a.ogg", "rb");
  int size = 86*1024/8/4;
  char buffer[size];
  int n;
  while ((n = fread(buffer, 1, size, file)) > 0) {
    g_printerr("read %d of data\n", n);
    process_data(&data, buffer, n);
  }
  fclose(file);
  g_printerr("finished reading data\n");
  end_request(&data);
  usleep(250000);
  finish_request(&data);
  // Switch to second request and do it again.
  data.request_id = "job2";
  start_request("", &data);
  file = fopen("./a.ogg", "rb");
  while ((n = fread(buffer, 1, size, file)) > 0) {
    g_printerr("read %d of data\n", n);
    process_data(&data, buffer, n);
  }
  fclose(file);
  g_printerr("finished reading data again\n");
  end_request(&data);
  usleep(250000);
  finish_request(&data);
  g_printerr("waiting for the gstreamer thread to end...\n");
  g_main_loop_quit (data.main_loop);
  pthread_join(thread, NULL);
  g_printerr("Closing\n");
  closeGstreamer(&data);
  g_printerr("Exit OK\n");
  return 0;
}
```